# How do I use vi to delete text on ALL lines up to and including the eighth instance of a pipe character?

Tags: vi

I know I can use something like d////////| on an individual line to get this to work, but I wanted to see if I can apply that universally so that command runs on all lines. What should I type?

I am going through some server logs, and everything to the left of the eighth pipe is useless to me in this instance (stuff like an IP address, username, timestamp, etc).

I want to do this using vi universally within the file starting at the beginning of each line, but: 
- not using any of those commands that start with a colon
- not using a macro

I know it might cut out a couple of lines that don't have notices or warnings, but that is what I am trying to do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
:%s/\([^|]*\n*[^|]*|\)\{8\}//g
```

Comment: Thank you for putting that together; I had no idea it would be so complicated but appreciate it!